# How to make windows 10 pro lite for hyper-v

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-10

do you guys know of any particular way to slim down windows 10 to be run successfully as a hyper v guest?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use the Windows 10 LTSB version. It come without the store and without edge, so can’t be lighter than that. The advantage of that versiin is there is no upgrade too, just update.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a shot...